# Unable to install dahdi - /usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, software-installation, asterisk, voip

I am trying to install dahdi in my centos 7 system using [this](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/05/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-centos-6/) link but having some errors

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete*
[root@localhost dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0]# make && make install && make config
make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi DAHDI_INCLUDE=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/include DAHDI_MODULES_EXTRA=" " HOTPLUG_FIRMWARE=yes modules DAHDI_BUILD_ALL=m
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
  VERSION /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpp_version.h

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 35 modules
WARNING: could not find /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/.vpmadt032_x86_64.o.cmd for /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/vpmadt032_x86_64.o
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
(cd tools && [ -f config.status ] || ./configure --with-dahdi=../linux)
make -C tools all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
Making all in xpp
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Making all in perl_modules
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Making all in doc
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/doc'
Making all in hotplug
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/hotplug'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/hotplug'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make -f ./Makefile.legacy top_srcdir=. srcdir=.  all
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi DAHDI_INCLUDE=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/include DAHDI_MODULES_EXTRA=" " HOTPLUG_FIRMWARE=yes modules DAHDI_BUILD_ALL=m
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
  VERSION /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpp_version.h

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 35 modules
WARNING: could not find /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/.vpmadt032_x86_64.o.cmd for /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/vpmadt032_x86_64.o
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
(cd tools && [ -f config.status ] || ./configure --with-dahdi=../linux)
make -C tools all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
Making all in xpp
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Making all in perl_modules
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Making all in doc
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/doc'
Making all in hotplug
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/hotplug'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/hotplug'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make -f ./Makefile.legacy top_srcdir=. srcdir=.  all
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make -C linux install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi DAHDI_INCLUDE=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/include DAHDI_MODULES_EXTRA=" " HOTPLUG_FIRMWARE=yes modules DAHDI_BUILD_ALL=m
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
  VERSION /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpp_version.h

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 35 modules
WARNING: could not find /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/.vpmadt032_x86_64.o.cmd for /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/vpmadt032_loader/vpmadt032_x86_64.o
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
build_tools/uninstall-modules dahdi 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi DAHDI_INCLUDE=/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/include DAHDI_MODULES_EXTRA=" " HOTPLUG_FIRMWARE=yes INSTALL_MOD_PATH= INSTALL_MOD_DIR=dahdi modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_dynamic.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_dynamic_eth.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_dynamic_ethmf.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_dynamic_loc.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_echocan_jpah.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_echocan_kb1.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_echocan_mg2.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_echocan_sec.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_echocan_sec2.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_transcode.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_vpmadt032_loader.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/oct612x/oct612x.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/pciradio.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/tor2.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/voicebus/dahdi_voicebus.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcaxx.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcb4xxp/wcb4xxp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcfxo.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wct1xxp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wct4xxp/wct4xxp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctc4xxp/wctc4xxp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm24xxp/wctdm24xxp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcte11xp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcte12xp/wcte12xp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcte13xp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wcte43x.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpd_bri.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpd_echo.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpd_fxo.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpd_fxs.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpd_pri.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpp.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/xpp_usb.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64'
[ `id -u` = 0 ] && /sbin/depmod -a 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 || :
for hdr in kernel.h user.h fasthdlc.h wctdm_user.h dahdi_config.h; do \
    install -D -m 644 include/dahdi/$hdr /usr/include/dahdi/$hdr; \
done
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware hotplug-install DESTDIR= HOTPLUG_FIRMWARE=yes
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
Firmware dahdi-fw-oct6114-032.bin is already installed with required version 1.05.01
Firmware dahdi-fw-oct6114-064.bin is already installed with required version 1.05.01
Firmware dahdi-fw-oct6114-128.bin is already installed with required version 1.05.01
Firmware dahdi-fw-oct6114-256.bin is already installed with required version 1.05.01
Firmware dahdi-fw-tc400m.bin is already installed with required version MR6.12
Firmware dahdi-fw-hx8.bin is already installed with required version 2.06
Firmware dahdi-fw-vpmoct032.bin is already installed with required version 1.12.0
Firmware dahdi-fw-te820.bin is already installed with required version 1.76
Firmware dahdi-fw-te133.bin is already installed with required version 7a001e
Firmware dahdi-fw-te134.bin is already installed with required version 780017
Firmware dahdi-fw-te435.bin is already installed with required version 13001e
Firmware dahdi-fw-te436.bin is already installed with required version 10017
Firmware dahdi-fw-a8a.bin is already installed with required version 1d0017
Firmware dahdi-fw-a8b.bin is already installed with required version 1f001e
Firmware dahdi-fw-a4a.bin is already installed with required version a0017
Firmware dahdi-fw-a4b.bin is already installed with required version d001e
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make -C drivers/dahdi/xpp/firmwares install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/firmwares'
mkdir -p /usr/share/dahdi
install ../init_card_1_30 ../init_card_2_30 ../init_card_3_30 ../init_card_4_30 ../init_card_5_30 /usr/share/dahdi/
install -m 644 ../XppConfig.pm USB_FW.hex USB_FW.201.hex USB_RECOV.hex FPGA_FXS.hex FPGA_1141.hex FPGA_1151.hex FPGA_1161.hex FPGA_1161.201.hex FPGA_1161.202.hex PIC_TYPE_1.hex PIC_TYPE_2.hex PIC_TYPE_3.hex PIC_TYPE_4.hex    /usr/share/dahdi/
for id in 202 203; do \
    if [ ! -r /usr/share/dahdi/USB_FW.$id.hex ]; then \
        ln -s USB_FW.201.hex /usr/share/dahdi/USB_FW.$id.hex;\
    fi; \
done
if [ ! -r /usr/share/dahdi/FPGA_1161.203.hex ]; then \
    ln -s FPGA_1161.201.hex /usr/share/dahdi/FPGA_1161.203.hex;\
fi
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/firmwares'
###################################################
###
### DAHDI installed successfully.
### If you have not done so before, install the package
### dahdi-tools.
###
###################################################
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
make -C tools install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
Making install in xpp
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Making install in perl_modules
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Hardware'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi/Hardware/USB.pm Dahdi/Hardware/PCI.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Hardware'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Config/Gen'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi/Config/Gen/Xpporder.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Spantypes.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Modules.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Users.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Freepbxdb.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Unicall.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Chandahdi.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/Assignedspans.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen/System.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Config/Gen'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Xpp'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi/Xpp/Line.pm Dahdi/Xpp/Xbus.pm Dahdi/Xpp/Xpd.pm Dahdi/Xpp/Mpp.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Xpp'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/.'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Config'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi/Config/Params.pm Dahdi/Config/Gen.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi/Config'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  Dahdi/Hardware.pm Dahdi/Span.pm Dahdi/Utils.pm Dahdi/Chans.pm Dahdi/Xpp.pm '/usr/local/share/perl5/Dahdi'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp/perl_modules'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/sbin'
 /usr/bin/install -c dahdi_registration xpp_sync lsdahdi xpp_blink dahdi_genconf dahdi_hardware twinstar '/usr/sbin'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/dahdi'
 /usr/bin/install -c xpp_fxloader astribank_hook waitfor_xpds '/usr/share/dahdi'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man8'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./dahdi_registration.8 ./xpp_sync.8 ./lsdahdi.8 ./xpp_blink.8 ./dahdi_genconf.8 ./dahdi_hardware.8 ./twinstar.8 '/usr/share/man/man8'
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_registration.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_sync.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./lsdahdi.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_blink.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_genconf.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_hardware.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./twinstar.8’: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [install-man8] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make: *** [install] Error 2
[root@localhost dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0]#
```

I have installed dahdi on centos 6 but never had this issue. I don't know what changed that cause this issue.

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_registration.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_sync.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./lsdahdi.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_blink.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_genconf.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_hardware.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./twinstar.8’: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why the modules are missing.

I have tried [similar](http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?p=214756) but didn't succeed. It would be helpful if anyone could point me to the right directions.

On trying @talezin solution it gave me

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64.debug'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux'
(cd tools && [ -f config.status ] || ./configure --with-dahdi=../linux)
make -C tools all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
Making all in xpp
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
Makefile:1299: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools/xpp'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/tools'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After removing the seperator issue here is a full stacktrace http://pastie.org/10683051 . It gave me

```
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/xpp/
```

and many more .

Comment: This one only first issue with dahdi.After that will be more. I have more then 15 years experience with dahdi/asterisk,but spend day and no success in install on centos 7. For now i can recommend you use centos 6 and wait till dahdi team fix all issues on rhel 7. Dahdi not usable on rhel7 now. If you need just modules, you can download dahdi-linux (not compleate version), issue with dahdi-tools.

Comment: @arheops it is not the problem of centos 7 because dahdi is working for me in centos 7.1 but not in centos 7.2 which is my case.Did you file any bug report yet?

Comment: I tested only on latest version. No, i not filed report.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in a Makefile and some man pages for Perl scripts are not generated. Those files ending in `.8` are man files.

This error seems to occur on CentOS 7 due to the `file` command version that prints different description for Perl scripts:

```
[root@centos-6.7 xpp]# file xpp_blink
xpp_blink: a /usr/bin/perl -w script text executable
[root@centos-6.7 xpp]# file --version
file-5.04

[root@centos-7.2 xpp]# file xpp_blink
xpp_blink: Perl script, ASCII text executable
[root@centos-7.2 xpp]# file -version
file-5.11
```

Because of this, Perl scripts are not detected correctly and their man pages are not generated.

To fix this, you can install the previous dadhi-linux version: http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/dahdi-linux-complete/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.2+2.10.2.tar.gz

You can also edit the Makefile and fix it manually. After running your first `make`, edit the generated **tools/xpp/Makefile** and change the following line (add a `grep -i`):

```diff
--- tools/xpp/Makefile.orig     2016-01-16 18:13:31.645000000 +0000
+++ tools/xpp/Makefile  2016-01-16 18:13:56.927000000 +0000
@@ -1296,7 +1296,7 @@
 all-local: $(perl_checks)

 %.8: %
-       @if file "$^" | cut -d: -f2 | grep -q perl; then \
+       @if file "$^" | cut -d: -f2 | grep -i -q perl; then \
                if pod2man --section 8 $^ > $@; then \
                        echo "  GEN      $@"; \
                else \
```

Then you can run `make all install config` again.

> INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi.ko
>
> Can't read private key

As [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/151151/thomas) said this is a warning and can be ignored. It means that it cannot sign that external kernel module because you are not a kernel/distro maintainer and you don't have the required keys to sign it.

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/DAHTOOL-70

Comment: Fixed in master: http://git.asterisk.org/gitweb/?p=dahdi/tools.git;a=commit;h=6057ef25e984a2c7f8327b872233ba610b9aabe6

Answer (score 0):

The errors concerning the `cannot stat` errors seem only to be related to  man pages.

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_registration.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_sync.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./lsdahdi.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./xpp_blink.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_genconf.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./dahdi_hardware.8’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat ‘./twinstar.8’: No such file or directory
```

A workaround would be to omit the man page installation in `tools/xpp/Makefile`.

```
[root@localhost dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.0+2.11.0]# diff tools/xpp/Makefile tools/xpp/Makefile.orig
1220c1220
< install-data-am: install-dist_dahditoolsSCRIPTS \
---
> install-data-am: install-dist_dahditoolsSCRIPTS install-man \
1284c1284
<   install-info install-info-am \
---
>   install-info install-info-am install-man install-man8 \
```

For the messages related to `Can't read private key`, I think the modules should be built and installed anyway and just means that you don't have the private key to sign it.
I did a quick `modprobe dahdi` after building this package, having the same messages, and a `lsmod` showed that the module was loaded.