# Downgrade Centos 7.2 to 7.1

Tags: centos, software-installation, system-installation, command, rolling-release

I am currently using `Centos 7.2.1511`(check from file /etc/redhat-release) and trying to downgrade it to `Centos 7.1.1503` (due to some [package  installation issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/unable-to-install-dahdi-usr-bin-install-cannot-stat-no-such-file-or-dire) in centos  7.2) using the command

```
yum downgrade redhat-release
```

But it says `Nothing to do`.

I also tried [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-yum-downgrade-packages-on-rhel-centos-fedora-scientific-linux/) tutorial but dint have any luck.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense whatsoever. Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) evolves by fixing bugs and other updates. Around each six months the collection of updates to the system are released as a point update (in this case, 7 plus updates to date is 7.2). In between, there is a rolling release of CentOS built from the up to date sources for RHEL (monthly they release installation media, i.e. here on November 2015, thus 7.2.1511). RHEL (and thus CentOS) are fixated on rigorous compatibility during each major version.

Comment: To add to this answer -- there is no supported downgrade from CentOS 7.2.1511 to 7.1.1503.  The only way that 'yum downgrade' would work is if the older package were available in a yum repo on your system.  If you really wanted to do that, you could possibly create new yum repo files that point to the old release on vault.centos.org, but next time you ran 'yum update' you'd be back at 7.2.1511 + software updates.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that in general you should try to use the latest versions. That having been said, there are definitely legitimate cases in which you may wish temporarily to revert to a previous state and which undoing an update (e.g., backing down from a recent upgrade from CentOS 7.1 to 7.2) might be needed. Examples could include finding out after the fat that a needed item of software is not yet available for the new release.

In such cases, "[yum history](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumHistory)" is your friend:

```
yum history
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    39 | update                   | 2016-11-25 21:27 | I, U           |  151 E<
[...]
# yum history undo 39
[... reverts back to previous state before "yum update"...]
```

If you run into problems with packages that are protected, you can exclude them from the undo; e.g.:

```
# yum --exclude=systemd --exclude=yum history undo 39
```